# xamarin.forms scrollView vs TableView vs listView

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, tableview, scrollview, datatemplateselector

- Checked on android

I need to create a Content Page with a list of max 30~ record.

i have 3 different types of cell, and inside the cell i have a button that if pressing on it will add image to the specific cell - (adding ImageView as a child to the Cell's stack layout) which will increase the cell height.

What's the best approach to develop ?

I have tried ScrollView but the it take time to build the page (a few seconds), and scrolling is smooth, but after adding an image the scrolling it's not smooth anymore.

The TableView I have tried is also slow building the page and the scrolling is also not smooth at all.

In the ListView with DataTemplateSelctros I have tried, page upload time was quite fast but still the scrolling after adding the image was slow.

Is there another option ? How can i improve scrolling after adding an image

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend list view with data template selectors.

There are things you can do to speed up the scrolling.

The first is to use a caching strategy on the list view.

Use

> CachingStrategy="RecycleElementAndDataTemplate"

[Here is an article on improving list view performance](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance/)

The second is to use FFImageLoading to display the images.

https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading

This reduces the memory usage and improves the display speed of images.